# Uber To Cater for different location pickup but same location dropoff

Tags: uber-api

I'm looking to make use of uber for a service I'd like to offer, the pickup location will always be different, and the drop off will always be the same.

Once the service is completed, the pickup for that specific service, will be the same location mentioned aboved, and the drop off will be the different location each time.

I'd like to know if there is a dashboard that is offered by uber to manually create these trips until I integrate the API into the web application

Comment: you might also be interested in Uber deeplinks: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction   "The setPickup action is a very powerful deep linking feature which allows you to launch the Uber app and do any combination of setting pickup, drop-off, and product selection."

Comment: Thanks Kyle :) Will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Uber does not have this kind of dashboard you are looking for - to create ride requests manually, but until you integrate the API calls into your web app - you can use CURL to manually invoke our API endpoints. Another option is to use Postman, or SoapUI.

Please check our [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#creating-a-ride-request) for CURL example.

Note: you will need to [authenticate](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token) your user before you can make ride request - and get access_token.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \
 '{"product_id": "821415d8-3bd5-4e27-9604-194e4359a449", "start_latitude":"37.775232", "start_longitude": "-122.4197513", "end_latitude":"37.7899886", "end_longitude": "-122.4021253","fare_id":"650235cb925e3503e87f14e62f9ef3e90beb0e14d893395c4b8e5118f1ac872c"}' \
  https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much for the reply Sasa! :)